# Conncting between react and Web-API project- The object arrives to the server with null and 0

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a project written in React and web API-C#
when I send a post request with data ,it comes to the controller initialized with nulls and 0

setting object in react:

```js
class user {
    UserID
    FirstName
    LastName
    SMS
    Email
    Phone
    RoleID
    UserName
    Password
    Dock
    DocName
    status

    constructor(userID = null, FirstName = null, LastName = null, SMS = null, Email = null, Phone = null, RoleID = null, userName = null, Password = null, document = null, docName = null, status = true) {
        this.UserID = userID
        this.FirstName = FirstName
        this.LastName = LastName
        this.SMS = SMS
        this.Email = Email
        this.Phone = Phone
        this.RoleID = RoleID
        this.UserName = userName
        this.Password = Password
        this.Dock = document
        this.DocName = docName
        this.status = status
    }

}
export default user
```

in C#:

```html
public class UserDTO
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string SMS { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Dock { get; set; }
        public string DocName { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public UserDTO()
        {

        }
}
```

sending to server:

```js
const use1 = new UserObject(1, 'aa', 'bb', null, null, null, 3);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => { Axios.post('https://localhost:44368/api/User/AddUser', JSON.stringify((use1)),).then(res => { console.log(res.data) }) }} >post with object</button>
         </div>

    )
```

in the client side it's full,
[image: screenshot 1]

and in the server,
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: try something like this when you post  : ...JSON.stringify({ ud : use1})...

Comment: I tried it,it doesn't help...